# how to learn "Animations in COCOS2D"

Tags: iphone, animation, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to cocos2d animations and I want to learn it , as always I stops at the point of animation while making iPhone games in cocos2d.

Can any one suggest me the way to learn such animations, so that games animation creating will become easy to make.

Thanks.

Comment: If any one knows better way to learn such animations in cocos2d, if any good way or some good information i.e. to the point so that animations in iphone with cocos2d will be easy to create.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems like there are 2 ways to go - either your sprites are laid out in a regular fashion and so can be picked off the sprite sheet in a programmatic way, like this first example. The other way is to use a tool like Zwoptex to create the sprite sheet and a corresponding plist that tells Cocos2d where to find the images on the sheet, see second example.

Tutorial for getting sprites off a sheet, using a regular layout:

http://getsetgames.com/2010/04/18/how-to-animate-sprites-in-cocos2d/

The basics are:

1. Get your images into one large image/texture
2. Create a CCSpriteSheet using that texture
3. Create a CCSprite using one of the images in your sprite sheet
4. Create a CCAnimation and populate it with CCSpriteFrame's - each representing a frame in the animation
5. Create a CCAnimate action to manage showing each frame and run it on sprite, voila.

The alternative is to use a tool like [Zwoptex](http://zwoptexapp.com/) to configure your images on a sheet which will export the sprite sheet and a plist of details of the images on it.

The first third of this tutorial explains it:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone

Hope that helps,
Chris

Comment: Thanks buddy this is a nice one.

Answer (score 5):

There are several cocos2d tutorials avaliable around the net. Also take a look at their docs. Another good resource can be github.com where you'll find at least couple of opensource games made in cocos2d

Answer (score 2):

There are Mainly 2 tools I use for the animation of the images they are:

1. [Texture Packer](http://www.texturepacker.com/cocos2d/xcode4-integration-tutorial-of-texturepacker-for-cocos2d-and-sparrow-framework/)
2. [Zwoptex](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d)

These 2 tools are great to work with it. The Texture Packer has also the integrated the Physics Editor which can be used to integrate the physics in the game. You can get the tutorial of both these animations from [Ray Wenderlich Demos.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This course helps you to build a game with Cocos2D, however it costs 99$. But animations are covered in the course, so you might look into that direction as well:

[Click here](http://ude.my/vUZpx4)