# iOS, what graphics / gaming libraries / tool should I use for a kids education tool? Please discuss

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, core-animation, core-graphics

I need to improve the fun factor in my kids educational puzzle app. At the moment my app isn't fun, in fact the word puzzle makes it sound fun, but it's more of a learning tool.

So I figure, that I need to add some animation / effects. At this stage I don't know if that means sprites, I guess it may well do.

I've done no graphics programming. I am keen to delve into game programming, at least to get a taste of it, so I'd have a little experience if I ever decided to write a game.

However, my priorities here are to develop something reasonably quickly, say 20 hours roughly (I just mention that so I don't end up having to re-invent the wheel and spend 6 months on it) and my zero budget.

So I guess my question is, what graphics / game libraries should I use, which aren't going to be massively complicated to use, but give me a good grounding in game development, where I don't have to buy a game engine etc?

Comment: Here's a flag you should look out for: _"As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for guidance."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well inhmo Cocos2d will do the job for you. The learning curve is not so high if you already know your way around iOS, it has a plethora of animations and a very strong community around it. Go through the documentation and ask the community for help with the type of animation effect you want to achieve. Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012163/how-to-learn-animations-in-cocos2d)